# Dropdown center alignment to button

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to align the `<ul>` dropdown centered to the button clicked as seen at http://jsfiddle.net/em0nh0pw/, but can't seem to get the right pull or class that needs to be used.

Specifically:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" name="ttl_frontpage" id="ttl_frontpage" data-toggle="dropdown">
  <span class="badge">10 min</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span>
</button>
<ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="ttl_frontpage_menu">
 <li><a href="#" data-value="60">1 min</a></li>
[..]
</ul>
```

Ideally, I'd love to see the `<ul>` menu show centered over the button both vertically and horizontally, but can't seem to get that right either. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to center the ul, it can be easily done using translateX.

You need to change one and add one line of CSS:

On `.dropdown-menu:`

```
left: 50%; /* instead of left: 0; */
transform: translateX(-50%); /* add this one */
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/em0nh0pw/16/)

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for :)

Answer (score 0):

need to remove `left : 0` for the `position: absolute` division

```js
$(".dropdown-menu li a").click(function() {
  $(this).parents(".dropdown").find('.btn').html('<span class="badge">' + $(this).text() + ' </span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span>');
  $(this).parents(".dropdown").find('input').val($(this).data('value'));
});
```

```css
.dropdown-menu{
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  left: 33%;
  right: 33%;
}
```

```html
<div class="panel-body">
  <form class="form-horizontal" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="domain" value="testwat.pro">

    <br>
    <fieldset id="sbsets" class="">
      <div class="panel panel-primary">
        <div class="panel-heading panel-heading-custom">
          <h3 class="panel-title">Front Page Cache</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-9" id="sbinfo">
              Configure how long requests for your front page should be cached for, in seconds.
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3" align="center">
              <div class="dropdown pull-center">
                <input type="hidden" name="ttl_frontpage">
                <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" name="ttl_frontpage" id="ttl_frontpage" data-toggle="dropdown"><span class="badge">10 min</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;
                  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span>
                </button>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="ttl_frontpage_menu">
                  <li><a href="#" data-value="60">1 min</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#" data-value="120">2 min</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#" data-value="300">5 min</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#" data-value="900">15 min</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#" data-value="1800">30 min</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#" data-value="3600">1 hour</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#" data-value="7200">2 hours</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#" data-value="10800">3 hours</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#" data-value="14400">4 hours</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#" data-value="18000">5 hours</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#" data-value="28800">8 hours</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#" data-value="43200">12 hours</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#" data-value="57600">16 hours</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#" data-value="86400">24 hours</a></li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </fieldset>

    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-md-2">
        <input type="submit" id="save_settings" name="save_settings" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary">
        <input type="submit" id="reset_settings" name="reset_settings" value="Reset" class="btn btn-primary">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-10 control-label">
        <span><h5><i>Settings changes can take up to 2 minutes to take effect.</i></h5></span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

here is the working **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/em0nh0pw/15/)**

Answer (score 0):

It's because, by default any `div` element is rendered as `block` which means it get's `width:100%` from the browser. Bootstrap has given `.dropdown` class `position:relative;` property. And 'dropdown-menu' has `position:absolute;` property, so following it's default behavior it starts from extreme left. 
You need to understand this well.

To get proper output, make 2 changes. 
Use `text-align:center` to your parent div and add `inline-block` property via a class along with `.dropdown` class. It will remove the extra `width` coming from `display:block;` and aligns your output properly.

```js
$(".dropdown-menu li a").click(function() {
  $(this).parents(".dropdown").find('.btn').html('<span class="badge">' + $(this).text() + ' </span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span>');
  $(this).parents(".dropdown").find('input').val($(this).data('value'));
});
```

```css
.inline-block {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="panel-body">
  <form class="form-horizontal" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="domain" value="testwat.pro">

    <br>
    <fieldset id="sbsets" class="">
      <div class="panel panel-primary">
        <div class="panel-heading panel-heading-custom">
          <h3 class="panel-title">Front Page Cache</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-9" id="sbinfo">
              Configure how long requests for your front page should be cached for, in seconds.
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3 text-center" align="center"> <!-- to align child content in center -->
              <div class="dropdown inline-block"> <!-- added inline-block class -->
                <input type="hidden" name="ttl_frontpage">
                <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" name="ttl_frontpage" id="ttl_frontpage" data-toggle="dropdown"><span class="badge">10 min</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;
                  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span>
                </button>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="ttl_frontpage_menu">
                  <li><a href="#" data-value="60">1 min</a>
                  </li>
                  <li><a href="#" data-value="120">2 min</a>
                  </li>
                  <li><a href="#" data-value="300">5 min</a>
                  </li>
                  <li><a href="#" data-value="900">15 min</a>
                  </li>
                  <li><a href="#" data-value="1800">30 min</a>
                  </li>
                  <li><a href="#" data-value="3600">1 hour</a>
                  </li>
                  <li><a href="#" data-value="7200">2 hours</a>
                  </li>
                  <li><a href="#" data-value="10800">3 hours</a>
                  </li>
                  <li><a href="#" data-value="14400">4 hours</a>
                  </li>
                  <li><a href="#" data-value="18000">5 hours</a>
                  </li>
                  <li><a href="#" data-value="28800">8 hours</a>
                  </li>
                  <li><a href="#" data-value="43200">12 hours</a>
                  </li>
                  <li><a href="#" data-value="57600">16 hours</a>
                  </li>
                  <li><a href="#" data-value="86400">24 hours</a>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </fieldset>

    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-md-2">
        <input type="submit" id="save_settings" name="save_settings" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary">
        <input type="submit" id="reset_settings" name="reset_settings" value="Reset" class="btn btn-primary">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-10 control-label">
        <span><h5><i>Settings changes can take up to 2 minutes to take effect.</i></h5></span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```